# Install apostropheCMS on plesk obsidian, error with npm path

Tags: node.js, plesk, apostrophe-cms

I'm quite new to node.js, I'm trying to install apostropheCMS on a plesk obsidian server (ubuntu 16)

I could install the nodeJS package on plesk, and made NPM commande global, so, when I go to my website folder (ex : /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite using SSH), I'm able to do "npm -v" command, it return me "6.9.0"

Now I follow the apostropheCMS starting guide, that say me to do that command :

```
npm install -g apostrophe-cli
```

It return me an error :

> checkPermissions Missing write access to
> /opt/plesk/node/12/lib/node_modules

I can understand and I'm connected with the user that have access to that web space (not root user). I would like to install node_modules to the web space I defined (so, in /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite/node_modules) but this is where I'm stuck, I don't know how to do that.

Thank you for your help

-- A guy trying to give interests to node ^^'

Comment: If you're still trying to figure this out, this is an issue with directory permissions. The cause of the issue is actually nothing to do with either Node or Apostrophe-CMS. You'll need some way to give your user write permissions to that folder - that's the only way to resolve the problem. If you have CLI access to the server, you can use the command specified here: https://talk.plesk.com/threads/npm-install-permission-denied.345289/. Otherwise, you will likely need to talk to whoever is hosting your Plesk install to see how to adjust permissions for your directory.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `apostrophe-cli` directly on a server. The apostrophe CLI is designed for use on your own computer, to get your project started — it is intended for a development environment. You would deploy to a server later in the process and the apostrophe CLI would not be needed there.

However you could install it on your server by configuring npm to install packages personally for the current user, rather than trying to do it in a location that can only be written to by the root user:

```
npm config set prefix "${HOME}/.npm-packages"
```

Then you would be able to use the apostrophe CLI in your hosting space. Just keep in mind that you would be best off developing locally and deploying to a server later. On a Mac or Linux computer you can follow the Apostrophe tutorials directly, on Windows we recommend installing the official Windows Subsystem for Linux or using virtualbox to install Ubuntu Linux.